# Node ES6 class event emitter function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, eventemitter, es6-class

I'm trying to create a class for which all instances respond to an event:

```
const events = require("events");
const eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();

class Camera {
    constructor(ip) {
        this.ip = ip;     
    }

    eventEmitter.on("recordVideo", recordClip);

    recordClip() {
        console.log("running record video");
    }
}

// emit event once a minute
setInterval(function(){
    eventEmitter.emit('recordVideo');
}, 1000*60);
```

The recordClip function never seems to be called. Is this possible?

*I also tried running `this.recordClip` instead of `recordClip`.*

Comment: Why do you have the statement in the class declaration and not inside the constructor or some other method?

Comment: "all instances" also means "no instance" when you haven't instantiated any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move it inside the constructor.

```
const events = require("events");
const eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();

class Camera {
    constructor(ip) {
        this.ip = ip;
        eventEmitter.on("recordVideo", this.recordClip.bind(this));
    }

    recordClip() {
        console.log("running record video");
    }
}
```