# Connect event emitter with instance of each ES6 class in node

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, eventemitter, es6-class

I'm trying to associate each instance of a class with an event emitter. I'm trying the following:

```
const events = require("events");
const eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();

class Camera {
    constructor(ip) {
        this.ip = ip;

        eventEmitter.on("recordVideo", function() {
            this.recordClip();
        });
    }

    recordClip() {
        console.log("record " + this.ip);
    }
}

var cam = new Camera("0.0.0.0");
eventEmitter.emit("recordVideo");
```

But I get back:

```
TypeError: this.recordClip is not a function
```

How can I have each instance of my class listen for the event?

Comment: Why not just use the code from [the answer you've already gotten](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45601755/1048572)?

Comment: @bergi sorry, I just copied and pasted my function call into the constructor. I didn't notice the bind change that was made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue here is that `this` is in the context of the event emitter, not the class. So, `eventEmitter` does not have `recordClip` as a method. You need to either lexically bind your callback with an arrow function:

(Personally, I think this is the best, and most modern/readable way to do this)

```
eventEmitter.on("recordVideo", () => {
    this.recordClip();
});
```

Or, you need to bind the proper scope:

```
eventEmitter.on("recordVideo", function() {
    this.recordClip();
}).bind(this);
```

Or you can make a reference to `this` via the `self` methodology:

```
class Camera {
    constructor(ip) {
        this.ip = ip;
        const self = this; //assign this to self
        eventEmitter.on("recordVideo", function() {
            self.recordClip(); //use self, not this here
        });
    }

    recordClip() {
        console.log("record " + this.ip);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know which of these methods would be considered more standard, or more readable?

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride I added that in my edit actually :) I think using the arrow function is the most standard/readable methodology here.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the context in the callback function is not referencing what you expect it to. Add an arrow function.

```
const events = require("events");
const eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();

class Camera {
   constructor(ip) {
     this.ip = ip;

      eventEmitter.on("recordVideo", () => {
        this.recordClip();
      });
   }

   recordClip() {
      console.log("record " + this.ip);
   }
}

   var cam = new Camera("0.0.0.0");
   eventEmitter.emit("recordVideo");
```

Here is some docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions